# How to find files with highest number in file name

Tags: linux, bash, file

I have a folder on a linux server with a bunch of files in it, every time a file is revised, it gets a new number.  there are many files, and can be many revisions.  This does not need to be recursive, as the files are stored in a flat file system

I would like a command to give me the list of the files with the highest number.

```
file1.rtf
file2.rtf
file3.rtf
file_1.doc
file_2.doc
anotherfile1.txt
anotherfile2.txt
someotherfile1.rtf
someotherfile2.rtf
someotherfile12.rtf
```

I am looking to get a list of files like...

```
file3.rtf
file_2.doc
anotherfile2.txt
someotherfile12.rtf
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Since the numbers are assigned sequentially as files are created, would it not be sufficient to simply find the most recently created files, regardless of name?

Comment: Create time may not be accurate, and it may not be precise enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl). It uses a regular expression to extract last number before the extension and uses a hash to save only the file with the biggest number:

```
perl -e '
    for ( @ARGV ) { 
        next unless m/\A(.*?)(\d+)(\.[^.]+)\Z/;
        $key = $1 . $3;
        if ( ! exists $file{ $key } or $file{ $key }->[0] < $2 ) {
            $file{ $key } = [$2, $_];
        }
    }
    for $f ( keys %file ) {
        printf qq|%s\n|, $file{ $f }->[1];
    }
' *
```

Assuming current directory has the files you provided in your question, it yields:

```
anotherfile2.txt
file_2.doc
file3.rtf
someotherfile12.rtf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *; do 
    [[ $f =~ ([^0-9]+)([0-9]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/$f"
done | 
sort -t/ -k1,1 -k2,2rn | 
awk -F/ '!seen[$1]++ {print $3}'
```

```
anotherfile2.txt
file3.rtf
file_2.doc
someotherfile12.rtf
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as intended!
The sort was a nice added touch!